# Nesting async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am creating a script to collect a tracklist per release from discogs.
My getTracklist is executed after getLabelReleases. The problem here is that it needs to execute while it's working on a specific release. (so the array tracklist can be filled up with the appropriate tracks)

How can I fix this and can somebody explain what is going on.

```
 function getLabelReleases(label, callback) {
   label['releases'] = [];

   var db = new Discogs().database();
   db.getLabelReleases(label.id, function(err, data){
       //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

       data.releases.forEach(function(release, index) {
         //console.log(pretty(release));
         label['releases'][index]= {};

         label['releases'][index]['order']=index+1;
         label['releases'][index]['id']=release.id;
         label['releases'][index]['catno']=release.catno;
         label['releases'][index]['year']=release.year;
         label['releases'][index]['title']=release.title;
         label['releases'][index]['tracklist']=getTracklist(release.id);

       });
       //console.log(pretty(label));
       callback ? callback(label) : null;
   });
 }
```

This is the function I use to create the tracklist

```
 function getTracklist(releaseId) {
   var tracklist = [];

   var db = new Discogs().database();
   db.getRelease(releaseId, function(err, data){

       //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        console.log('get tracklist for '+releaseId)

       discogsTracklist = data.tracklist;

       discogsTracklist.forEach(function(track, index) {
         //console.log(track.title);
         tracklist[index] = {};
         tracklist[index].order = index+1;
         tracklist[index].position = track.position;
         tracklist[index].title = track.title;

         var artists = [];
         track.artists && track.artists.forEach(function(artist, index) {
           artists[index] = artist.name;
         })
         tracklist[index].artists = artists.join(" & ");

       })

       //console.log(tracklist);
       return tracklist;
   });

 }
```

I tried filling the tracklist with a callback but it is still executed in the end. Where should I place the callback?

The catch is I need the index parameter to determine position in the release array.

```
   41 function getLabelReleases(label, callback) {
   42   label['releases'] = [];
   43   
   44   var db = new Discogs().database();
   45   db.getLabelReleases(label.id, function(err, data){
   46       //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
   47       
   48       data.releases.forEach(function(release, index) {
   49         //console.log(pretty(release));
   50         label['releases'][index]= {};
   51         
   52         label['releases'][index]['order']=index+1;
   53         label['releases'][index]['id']=release.id;
   54         label['releases'][index]['catno']=release.catno;
   55         label['releases'][index]['year']=release.year;
   56         label['releases'][index]['title']=release.title;
~  57         
+  58         getTracklist(release.id, function (tracklist) {
+  59           label['releases'][index]['tracklist']=tracklist;
+  60         });
+  61 
   62          
   63       });
   64       //console.log(pretty(label));
   65       if(callback) callback(label);
   66   });
   67 }
```

and the callback is added:

```
   70 // TRACKLIST
   71 
~  72 function getTracklist(releaseId, callback) {
   73   var tracklist = [];
   74 
   75   var db = new Discogs().database();
   76   db.getRelease(releaseId, function(err, data){
   77 
   78       //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
   79        console.log('get tracklist for '+releaseId)
   80 
   81       discogsTracklist = data.tracklist;
   82 
   83       discogsTracklist.forEach(function(track, index) {
   84         //console.log(track.title);
   85         tracklist[index] = {};
   86         tracklist[index].order = index+1;
   87         tracklist[index].position = track.position;
   88         tracklist[index].title = track.title;
   89 
   90         var artists = [];
   91         track.artists && track.artists.forEach(function(artist, index) {
   92           artists[index] = artist.name;
   93         })
   94         tracklist[index].artists = artists.join(" & ");
   95 
   96       })
   97 
   98       //console.log(tracklist);
~  99       if(callback) callback(tracklist);
  100   });
```

Comment: You want to read about Promises, especially [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: You already did you use a callback correctly in `getLabelReleases`. Do the same for `getTracklist` - you cannot simply `return` a value from an asynchronous callback.

Comment: @Bergi I tried changing it to  getTracklist(release.id, function (tracklist) {label['releases'][index]['tracklist']=tracklist; }); , can you tell me where I am supposed to place the getTracklist callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you cannot use Promises or async/await, take look at this library: 
https://github.com/caolan/async

Now for a promise solution, you need to promisify the `getTracklist` function first:

```
function getTracklist(releaseId) {
    var tracklist = [];
    var db = new Discogs().database();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.getRelease(releaseId, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            console.log('get tracklist for ' + releaseId)
            discogsTracklist = data.tracklist;
            discogsTracklist.forEach(function (track, index) {
                //console.log(track.title);
                tracklist[index] = {};
                tracklist[index].order = index + 1;
                tracklist[index].position = track.position;
                tracklist[index].title = track.title;
                var artists = [];
                track.artists && track.artists.forEach(function (artist, index) {
                    artists[index] = artist.name;
                })
                tracklist[index].artists = artists.join(" & ");
            })
            //console.log(tracklist);
            resolve(tracklist);
        });
    });

}
```

Then you instead of `forEach` you can `map` the tracks to Promises and wait for all of them to finish using `Promise.all`:

```
function getLabelReleases(label, callback) {
    label['releases'] = [];

    var db = new Discogs().database();
    db.getLabelReleases(label.id, function (err, data) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

        Promise.all(data.releases.map(function (release, index) {
            //console.log(pretty(release));
            label['releases'][index] = {};

            label['releases'][index]['order'] = index + 1;
            label['releases'][index]['id'] = release.id;
            label['releases'][index]['catno'] = release.catno;
            label['releases'][index]['year'] = release.year;
            label['releases'][index]['title'] = release.title;

            return getTracklist(release.id).then((tracklist) => {
                label['releases'][index]['tracklist'] = tracklist;
                return tracklist;
            });


        })).then(() => {
            //console.log(pretty(label));
            if (callback) callback(label);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: why do I need to use promises? am I reasoning correctly that I need a promise to ensure the tracklist is fully created before executing the callback?

Comment: Exactly. You need to wait for the tracklist to load before you move on to the next iteration. You can achive this with callbacks too if you don't want to use promises but you will have to include the async.js library

Comment: thanks I will look into this, it's completely new for me. For now I fixed it using a callback. will test the promises later.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using following callback. Will investigate about the promises to see if this a better way.

```
  46 function getLabelReleases(label, callback) {
   47   label['releases'] = [];
   48 
   49   var db = new Discogs().database();
   50   db.getLabelReleases(label.id, function(err, data){
   51       //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
   52 
   53       data.releases.forEach(function(release, index) {
   54         //console.log(pretty(release));
~  55 
~  56         getTracklist(release.id, function (tracklist) {
~  57           label['releases'][index]= {};
~  58 
~  59           label['releases'][index]['order']=index+1;
~  60           label['releases'][index]['id']=release.id;
~  61           label['releases'][index]['catno']=release.catno;
~  62           label['releases'][index]['year']=release.year;
+  63           label['releases'][index]['title']=release.title;
+  64           label['releases'][index]['tracklist']=tracklist;
+  65 
+  66           if(callback) callback(label);
+  67         });
+  68 
   69 
_  70       });
   71   });
```